# Pointer to a Pointer of structs C

Tags: c, pointers, memory

Hi all I might have a hard time explaining this, but I will try my best.

I am creating a DLL that will be injected into a program. In order to access the data I want from inside the DLL I mapped the data to a "base address" in which is a pointer to another address. From there I have to increment that address by 0x34 in order to access my data. I figured i could use structs to my advantage but it doesnt seem to be working. The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to increment the second address to obtain the final pointer to my data.

What I have is this

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

typedef struct
{
    DWORD Some_Int;
    //big struct of DWORDS simulating what is in the applicaiton.
    //shortened for posting
}DATA;

typedef struct
{
    BYTE Unknown[0x34];
    DATA *p_data;
}VARBASE;


DWORD WINAPI function()
{
    VARBASE *Stats = (VARBASE*)0x00BBC9CC;
    char lol[1000];

    sprintf(lol, "stats pointer: %p  |  DATA pointer: %p", Stats, Stats->p_data);
    SomeFunction(lol); //wrapper for MessageBoxA()

    return NULL;
}
```

Stats points to the right address, but I cant manage to read 0x34 bytes of data (or increment the pointer 0x34) in order to get the second pointer to my data set. When I use this current code p_data gets set to 0000155A or something similar, when it should be in the 0A0***** range, which causes a segfault when read. I know my math is correct because Ive opened the application up in a memory mapper like CheatEngine and I can specifically add the base pointer -> address + 0x34 -> my data from inside CheatEngine.

Is there a easier way to go about this rather then using a base structure to point to my data? Basically its pointer->pointer+0x34->data and the problem I am facing is that I cannot increment the second pointer and set it so I can access my data.

Comment: Undefined behaviour: `sprintf(lol, "stats pointer: %p  |  DATA pointer: %p", Stats, Stats->p_data);`. `%p` corresponds to an argument with the type `void *`. Passing any other type (except perhaps `char *`) produces undefined behaviour.

Comment: interesting. what is the proper way to print an address of a pointer than.

Comment: Uhh, by passing a `void *` argument... Which book are you reading?

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that padding may exist between the two members of your struct? This is one example of "How do I do something *the wrong way*?". Perhaps you'd be better off telling us *which problem your program is to solve*.

If you're certain that `0x00BBC9CC + 34` is suitably aligned to point to a `DWORD *`, then why not jump straight to the point: `DWORD **some_int = 0x00BBC9CC + 34;`..? Where are you getting this address from, by the way? Unfortunately, Win32 C programmers rarely actually produce C programs.

Comment: :)  Same is true for Linux programmers though.  How many void main() or malloc casting programs are posted a day here, and tagged as C?

Comment: 0x00bbc9cc points to 0x0a1ecdc0 which i then need to increment by 0x34, then i have to take that address and grab the data in which it points to. The base address never changes i have verified this by restarting the application many times and the same math always points to the same data. 0x00bbc9cc -> 0x0a1ecdc0+34 -> my_data(4 bytes long) edit: the reason I cannot do that is because there is more than one value i wish to pull (there are about 35 of them). i thought if i pointed my structure with varaibles the same size as what is in the application that I could just read what i pleased

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I needed to deference the base address pointer and pass that value to my VARBASE structure.

```
DWORD WINAPI function()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("testaddr.txt", "a+");
    DWORD *ptr = (DWORD*)0x00BBC9CC;
    VARBASE *Stats = (VARBASE*)*ptr;
    //removed debug output to file
    fclose(fp);
    return NULL;
}
```